# Uso de vírgula antes de "e" para separar a última oração em uma lista de orações coordenadas

Tags: vírgula

É permitido o uso da vírgula para separar a última oração nas seguintes frases?

> Rosas são vermelhas, lírios são brancos[,] e girassóis são amarelos.
>
> O volume do paralelepípedo é dado por *V = a l c*, onde *a* é a altura, *l* é a largura[,] e *c* é o comprimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. A vírgula deve ser usada para separar orações com sujeitos diferentes que estão no mesmo período. Em todas as frases, a vírgula está servindo para separar orações com sujeitos distintos: rosas, lírios e girassóis.

A vírgula após a conjunção *e* também servirá para evitar ambiguidade:

> Eu gosto de filme e meu amigo não
> Eu gosto de filme, e meu amigo não.

A vírgula também deve¹ ser adicionada antes da conjunção supramencionada quando a oração for coordenada adversativa.

> Eles sofrem duras privações, e [= mas] não se queixam.

<sup>¹ Alguns gramáticos afirmam que não há diferenças. Para evitar possíveis ambiguidades, é recomendado o uso.</sup>